# ExtJS direct with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs, ext-direct

I've been looking at using [ExtJS Direct](http://extjs.com/products/extjs/direct.php) with ASP.NET MVC but it doesn't seem to play too nicely with MVC's routing. Has anyone had any luck implementing it with ASP.NET MVC? I don't want the actual implementation details, just want to know if anyone has been able to actually get it working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

implementation of it [here](http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=72245) on extjs forums

Comment: the implementation is a little flawed, but it certainly gives the right direction to go with... thanks